# ON_CONTROL_RANGE C++ error invalid type conversion

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, mfc

I am programming the windows base application using MFC. when I was trying to use `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` function there is an error message popped up.

Visual Studio was used to build the app.

**error**

*E0171 invalid type conversion*

*why is this error comes up,
give me a hint*

Code

```
#define IDC_USR_MANUAL_TUNING_CH1_CHECK 1134
#define IDC_USR_MANUAL_TUNING_CH7_CHECK 1140

ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, IDC_USR_MANUAL_TUNING_CH1_CHECK, IDC_USR_MANUAL_TUNING_CH8_CHECK, OnUsrManualTuningChCheck) 


void CMainteManualTuningDialog::OnUsrManualTuningChCheck(int nId)
{
    if (FALSE == m_bInitFlag)       // Initialization flag TRUE: Initialized / FALSE: Uninitialized
    {
        return;
    }

    UpdateData(TRUE);

    int nChCnt = nId - IDC_USR_MANUAL_TUNING_CH1_CHECK;
    if ((CH1 > nChCnt) || (CH8 < nChCnt))
    {
        return;
    }
    // unused
    if (FALSE == m_bUseCheck[nChCnt])
    {
        if (nChCnt == m_rbutCh)
        {
            MessageBox("While selecting a channel, it cannot be invalidated.");
            m_bUseCheck[nChCnt] = TRUE;     // invalid
        }
        else
        {
            m_butUseCheck[nChCnt].SetWindowText(MSG_IGNORE);    // Ignore
            m_butChSel[nChCnt].EnableWindow(FALSE);         // invalid
            g_eTuningStat[nChCnt] = E_TUNING_STAT_NONE;         // unused
            m_strStatCh[nChCnt] = MSG_NONE;                     // unused
            if (FALSE == m_clp->ZeroSetSend(nChCnt, m_pcTuningData))
            {
                ((CMicroDetectorView*)m_hpView)->PostMessage(WM_USR_ALARM, eAPP_T);
            }
        }
    }
    // use
    else
    {
        m_butUseCheck[nChCnt].SetWindowText(MSG_USE);   // Use
        m_butChSel[nChCnt].EnableWindow(TRUE);      // Effectiveness
        // Unadjusted the adjustment status
        SetStatStill(nChCnt);
    }

    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual compiler output (not Visual Studio's Error List output). Also, is the `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` macro inside your message map definition?

Comment: The code you show here is wrong, because `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` must be inside a message map. Is this real code or have you stripped it down? On *which line exactly* did you get the error message? Show the *verbatim error message*.

Comment: The handler for `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` is supposed to take a `UINT`, not `int`

Comment: You show CH7 yet in the range you have CH8

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the comment `int` was the error

Comment: Now please update the question with the **actual** compiler error, so that people can search for it. Compiler errors start with a capital `C`. You find them from the compiler output window (Alt+2 by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we use the `ON_CONTROL_RANGE(wNotifyCode, id, idLast, memberFxn)`
**memberFxn** Fn has to use **UINT** variables